# sort divs by its data attribute - type error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to sort `div` elements by data attribute values (`data-date`);

Getting type error - `a.attr is not a function`.

Any help?

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.title').sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.attr('data-date') < b.attr('data-date')) {return -1;}
 else {return 1;}
  }).appendTo('#titles');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='titles'>
  <div class='title' data-date="2017-11-05 07:29:35">lorem</div>
  <div class='title' data-date="2017-09-22 05:27:31">ipsum</div>
  <div class='title' data-date="2014-07-29 08:29:03">lorema</div>
  <div class='title' data-date="2016-12-04 05:04:14">ipsuma</div>
</div>

<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: The properties with numeric index in jQuery object are DOM elements, not jQuery objects, use `getAttribute` instead, and notice, that everything you get from the DOM, is string.

Comment: To directly use .att you have to use jquery, use getAttribute to use it with pure js

Comment: Try wrapping the a and b variables with `$( a ).attr(...`

Comment: @Teemu if everything is string then how to sort by date?

Comment: The values look like they'd be valid arguments for `Date` constructor.

Comment: `2016-12-04 05:04:14` would need to be changed to `2016-12-04T05:04:14` I believe for the Date constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Since a and b are DOM Elements, not jQuery objects, you can use the
// getAttribute method to get the date values.

// If you want to do a string sort, strings have a built in localeCompare
// method that returns the -1, 0, 1 sort expects
$('button').eq(0).on('click', function(){
  $('.title').sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.getAttribute('data-date').localeCompare(b.getAttribute('data-date'));
  }).appendTo('#titles');
});

// Or if you wanted to sort by dates, you'd need to fix the strings to a
// proper ISO format so Date knows how to parse them

$('button').eq(1).on('click', function(){
  $('.title').sort(function(a, b) {
                                           // replace space with T and append
                                           // a 000 timezone so the time does
                                           // not change
      var aDate = a.getAttribute('data-date').replace(/ /, 'T') + '.000Z';
      var bDate = b.getAttribute('data-date').replace(/ /, 'T') + '.000Z';
    
      return new Date( aDate ) - new Date( bDate );
  }).appendTo('#titles');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='titles'>
<div class='title' data-date="2017-11-05 07:29:35">lorem</div>
<div class='title' data-date="2017-09-22 05:27:31">ipsum</div>
<div class='title' data-date="2014-07-29 08:29:03">lorema</div>
<div class='title' data-date="2016-12-04 05:04:14">ipsuma</div>
</div>

<button>SORT BY STRING</button>
<button>SORT BY DATE</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Jquery to call `.attr`.
Here is the fixed code.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('.title').sort(function(a, b) {
   if ($(a).attr('data-date') < $(b).attr('data-date')) {return -1;}
   else {return 1;}
  }).appendTo('#titles');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='titles'>
<div class='title' data-date="2017-11-05 07:29:35">lorem</div>
<div class='title' data-date="2017-09-22 05:27:31">ipsum</div>
<div class='title' data-date="2014-07-29 08:29:03">lorema</div>
<div class='title' data-date="2016-12-04 05:04:14">ipsuma</div>
</div>

<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: This is awful, what is the point to convert the DOM element to a Jquery object, and then call a jQuery method which internally will convert the object back to DOM element and read the same attribute ..?

Comment: @Teemu you are right, I mentioned this on the comments for the questions before giving my answer but since this was an issue about Jquery I answered it to fix the problem the user had, in this case, to use `.attr`

Comment: @Teemu, your comment about double converting is usefull. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a vanilla JavaScript solution to your problem. Simple steps include querying the DOM for desired elements, accessing it's `date` attribute via `dataset`, and sorting the array based on the elements `dataset.data` value:

```js
function orderByDate(a, b) {
  if (new Date(a['date']) < new Date(b['date'])) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (new Date(a['date']) > new Date(b['date'])) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function reorder(data) {
  const titlesEl = document.querySelector('#titles');
  titlesEl.innerHTML = '';
  data.sort(orderByDate).forEach(o => {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o.key));
    titlesEl.appendChild(div);
  });
}

const divEls = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id=titles] > [class=title]'));


reorder(divEls.map(div => {
  return {
    //You need to access the dataset property to get data-*
    date: div.dataset.date,
    key: div.innerHTML
  }
}));
```

```html
<div id='titles'>
  <div class='title' data-date="2017-11-05 07:29:35">lorem</div>
  <div class='title' data-date="2017-09-22 05:27:31">ipsum</div>
  <div class='title' data-date="2014-07-29 08:29:03">lorema</div>
  <div class='title' data-date="2016-12-04 05:04:14">ipsuma</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

attr() is a jQuery method and to be able to use it on an HTML element you have to use $. So, instead of a.attr() write it as $(a).attr()